# How to put the variable names of pandas data frame on Diagonal of Seaborn PairGrid?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

The given below code is not working now(earlier it was working) to put the column names on the diagonal of Seaborn PairGrid.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

def diagfunc(x, **kws):
  ax = plt.gca()
  ax.annotate(x.name, xy=(0.05, 0.9), xycoords=ax.transAxes)

sns.PairGrid(iris).map_diag(diagfunc)
```

[image]

**At present it showing this error!**

```py
<ipython-input-137-f4d9b71087cb> in diagfunc(x, **kws)
      5 def diagfunc(x, **kws):
      6     ax = plt.gca()
----> 7     ax.annotate(x.name, xy=(0.05, 0.9), xycoords=ax.transAxes)
      8 
      9 sns.PairGrid(iris).map_diag(diagfunc)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Can anyone help me how to put the column name in diagonal?

Answer (score 1):

With minimal changes, I got this to work (python3.7.3, SeaBorn 0.9.0):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

# Add this before your call to map_diag
next_iris_label = iter(iris).__next__

def diagfunc(x, **kws):
  ax = plt.gca()
  #  replace x.name with `next_iris_label` call
  ax.annotate(next_iris_label(), xy=(0.05, 0.9), xycoords=ax.transAxes)

sns.PairGrid(iris).map_diag(diagfunc)
```

Output:
[image: Output of the obove python code when run in JupyterLab]

I dug into it and understood that the reason this fails is because once the IRIS dataset has been passed to `SeaBorn.PairGrid`, the original Names of observation columns are not retained. `map_diag` ends up calling `diagfunc` with diagonal components of the `PairGrid`, which do not have name property, let alone name anywhere else in the arguments passed.
Here is what is passed to the first time `diagfunc` is called:

```py
{
    #  this is what you passed as positional parameter
    #  As you'll notice `x` is just an array, and 
    #   does not have any additional properties like a label
    'x': array([5.1, 4.9, , ... 5.9]), 
    #  these get passed in as **kws
    'label': '_nolegend_', 
    'color': (0.12156862745098039, 0.4666666666666667, 0.7058823529411765)
}
```

Now, if we could somehow iterate over all labels in IRIS dataset, we could put each one against the diagnoals of the `PairGrid`. Since `diagfunc` is called each time and has a new scope, I found that having an iterator that returned a new label each time it was called solves that.

`next_iris_label` defined as

```py
next_iris_label = iter(iris).__next__
```

solves that problem. This only has one constraint that I dont like, you will need to reset this by creating a new instance of the iterator by the binding statement `next_iris_label = iter(iris).__next__` when you want to do such labelling again(otherwise it would throw a StopIteration error.)